# Fortran subroutine doesn't return to python

Tags: python, fortran, subroutine, f2py

I'm using fortran subroutine in my python code, subroutine runs but don't seem to return anything to python.

Here's my subroutine

```
subroutine gameo(N, matrix, newmat)

integer :: N 
integer :: matrix(10,10), maxit, newmat(10,10), naap


do i=1,N
do j=1,N

    naap = 0 !count neighbours
    do k=i-1,i+1
        do l=j-1,j+1
            if (k==i .AND. l==j) then
                continue
            else if (k>=N .OR. k<0) then
                continue
            else if (l>=N .OR. l<0) then
                continue
            else if (matrix(k,l) == 1) then
                naap = naap+1
            end if 
        end do
    end do
    if (matrix(i,j) ==1) then !update new array
        if (naap>3) then
            newmat(i,j) = 0
        else if (naap < 2) then
            newmat(i,j) = 0
        else 
            newmat(i,j)= 1
        end if
    else if (matrix(i,j) == 0) then
        if (naap==3) then
            newmat(i,j) = 1
        else 
            newmat(i,j) = 0
        end if
    end if          
end do
end do

end subroutine gameo
```

And here is my python code

```
N = 10
matrix = np.zeros((N,N))

for i in range(N):
    for j in range(N):
        matrix[i,j]=np.random.randint(0,2)

it = 0
maxit = 10

while it<maxit:
    newmat = np.zeros((N,N))

    newmat = gameo.gameo(N,matrix,newmat) #calling Fortran subroutine

    matrix = newmat
    it += 1
```

I also have problems on fortran arrays, I can't write 'matrix(N,N)', but have to assign it 'matrix(10,10)' instead.
I'm relatively new with python and with fortran i've been working for just few months.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. See how to create a [mcve].

Comment: Also, take a look at [this](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Conway%27s_Game_of_Life#Fortran) sample implementation of Conway's Game of Life in Fortran, for reference.